# Converting double field to integer in database view so ArcMap query layer can use field as unique identifier

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, fields-attributes, oracle-dbms, query-layer

I have a field in a table that is a double data type, but the values are actually integers. The table is from third-party software, so I don't have control of the field data types.

I'm attempting to make a database view of the table, and add it to ArcMap (which I believe makes it into a query layer).  Arcmap requires a unique identifier field be selected when the view is added to the map. There isn't a single unique field in the table, but the combination of two other fields plus the double field **is unique**. I plan to select all three fields as the unique id (sort of like a composite key). The problem is that it that ArcMap seemingly [does not recognize double fields as unique identifiers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/choose-unique-identifier.htm) (and probably for good reason). Text fields and integers seem to be recognized just fine.

As a workaround, I'm trying to convert the double field to an integer field in the database view. I've tried various combinations of the TO_NUMBER, ROUND, FLOOR, TRUNCATE, and CAST Oracle functions, with no success.

How can I get the table into ArcMap as a database view, and use the double field as a unique identifier?

Environment: Oracle 11g, SDE 10.3.1, ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1

**Update Jul-29-2016:**

The table is non-spatial. It will just be used to join to another non-spatial table about once per quarter for QC purposes. The table has ~20,000 records. There isn't a ROWID or OBJECTID field in the table, thus forcing me to find a workaround.

Comment: I don't recommend using this procedure.  The registered rowid column exists so that the graphics in the field of view and attribute rows in the table can be logically joined.  Working back to the shape from a calculated field when an attribute row is highlighted is not likely to be a pleasant task.  The id field should be an actual column, with an index.

Comment: Vince, I'm not sure I completely understand your comment, but perhaps more details will help. The table is non-spatial, and won't be used for any spatial purposes. It will just be used to join to another non-spatial table (a linear referencing table) about once a quarter for QC purposes. The table has ~20,000 records. Additionally, there is not a rowed or objected field in the table, so I'm forced to find a workaround. Do you still think this is a bad idea?

Comment: I think I'm starting to see what you mean, Vince. Using more than one column as the unique identifier, especially with a generated field, such as using CAST, is a DISASTER in ArcMap. Unexpected results is an understatement. Depending on the scenario, the CAST fields are being populated with wildly random numbers, such as -240000, 10000, 0, -1848000, 190000. These numbers are supposed to be 4 digit IDS! Frightening.

Comment: Joining on a computed column is bad juju, but I'm not used to it being that bad.  Does the value compute cleanly in SQLDeveloper or TOAD?  Please update the question with the extra details.

Comment: The view computes cleanly when brought into MS Access as a linked table. I don't have access to SQLDeveloper or TOAD..

Answer (score 4):

You have to [create the view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm) using a select statement with a [casting case](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html). For instance: SELECT CAST (miles AS INT)
Once your view is created, it should appear in the catalog of your database connection.

Comment: "NUMBER(38)" would be a better cast target.

Comment: Vince, why is "NUMBER(38)" a better choice?

Comment: Because "NUMBER(38)" is the type that generates the 32-bit integer that ArcGIS is expecting ("NUMBER" maps to a double)

Answer (score 3):

*Some points to add to the other answers that I learned through trial and error.*

If the Oracle table doesn't have a unique id field use [ROWNUM psudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm). (Note: **be aware that features might get a different number each time the query is called**.)

`cast(ROWNUM as number(38))`

In ArcGIS Pro I have to explicitly name the cast table, not sure if this applies to ArcMap also. Without the name the query runs successfully but when trying to open the table there is an `OID column has null value` error.

```
-- Use auto generated row number and rename
cast (ROWNUM  as number(38)) as OBJECTID
-- Use an existing unique id field and keep the same name
cast (PLOT_ID as number(38)) as PLOT_ID
```

Wildcard field selection won't work with cast:

```
select cast(…) as ID, * from DB.TABLE
```

Result:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
WARNING 001005: The output already exists.
ERROR 000358: Underlying DBMS error[ORA-00936: missing expression]
Failed to execute (MakeQueryLayer).
```

Which makes sense after thinking about it, because how would you stop the recursion? The ID field would be included again with the * selection.

Full python example:

```py
import arcpy
query = '''
select 
cast(ROWNUM  as number(38)) as OBJECTID,
cast(SAMPLE_ID AS NUMBER(38)) as SAMPLE_ID, 
LOCATION, UTM_EAST, UTM_NORTH, UTM_ZONE 
from ORADB.SAMPLE_LOCATIONS
'''
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management('path-to-oradb.sde','samples_table', query, 'OBJECTID')
```

**Sources:**

- Number(38) courtesy of @Vince, in this thread
- Rownum idea courtesy of [Ryan Monk](https://community.esri.com/thread/178045#comment-614813) and @Wilson in this very question, which I totally missed on first couple readings